# kafka ignite sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to replicate data from Kafka topic to apache ignite cluster. I have added ignite-core.jar along with all other required files in plugins and it's loaded in connector as per the logs. Still I'm facing this error. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

```
    INFO Instantiated connector string-ignite-connector with version 6.1.1-ccs of type class org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:284)
[2021-05-15 08:52:43,717] INFO Finished creating connector string-ignite-connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:310)
[2021-05-15 08:52:43,719] ERROR WorkerConnector{id=string-ignite-connector} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:193)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/util/typedef/internal/A
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector.start(IgniteSinkConnector.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:210)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:349)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:332)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.internal.A
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 12 more
[2021-05-15 08:52:43,723] ERROR Failed to create job for myconfig/ignite-connector.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110)
[2021-05-15 08:52:43,723] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to transition connector string-ignite-connector to state STARTED
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to transition connector string-ignite-connector to state STARTED
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/util/typedef/internal/A
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector.start(IgniteSinkConnector.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:210)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:349)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:332)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.internal.A
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: What connector did you install?

Comment: It's the same which comes with apache ignite binary pakage version 2.8.0 at path {IGNITE-HOME}/libs/optional/ignite-kafka

Comment: And that's the path you put in Connect `plugin.path`? You shouldn't move jar files around, only download if some are missing. You can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to accomplish the same goal

Comment: Yes I have done the same this class definition is present in ignite-core.jar It's placed at correct place and I read it has been loaded in creating connector. I have checked logs for it. But while running the same connector it's giving this error.

Comment: I've not used ignite. Is there a specific guide you followed to set this up so we can get a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, Thanks I could resolve it. I had changed 'plugin.path' to outer directory and it was inaccessible due to no read permissions. Thank you for help.

Comment: Feel free to provide your own answer below

Comment: In connector properties file plugin.path is mentioned but as the directory containing plugins was not permitted for read operation. Kafka was unable to read that jar class I changed it's permissions and moved it to the /share/java/kafka/ directory of from ${CONFLUENT_HOME} path. Now it is running

Comment: Rather than a comment, post an answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `ignite-kafka` module in your classpath, but not `ignite-core` and its dependencies, which is also needed. My understanding ends there.