# Can we write our own consumers to push Ignite data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13442

Regarding the above issue, this is not yet implemented/fixed.

Alternatively, in the Sink Connector place, can we write our own consumers which listen to Kafka queue for cache events? Where those consumers will check those events and execute on the specified cluster for DC replication.

Comment: Related? https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/reference/connectors/camel-ignite-compute-kafka-sink-connector.html + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544969/kafka-ignite-sink-connector

Answer (score 0):

Since Ignite is Open Source, it might be easier to fix it yourself than to write your own consumer from scratch.

Having said that, there's nothing "special" about the Kafka adapter. It's entirely possible to write an application that reads from Kafka and sends puts or removes to an Ignite cluster.

Comment: Even if I edit that adapter code, can I use that modified code for commercial use?

Comment: The Apache Licence 2.0 allows for commercial use.