# IgniteSinkTask in strimz kube cluster with kafka 3

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, ignite

I try to run IgniteSinkConnector in my kube cluster with strimzi and kafka 3. I add all dependency and I can see that IgniteSinkConnector was added. Problem is static classes in   this IgniteSinkTask which cannot be found even jar contains all this classes. I found that this connector still using kafka 2. It is ok to use usi SinkConnector based on kafka 2 in kafka 3 environment ? And how to fix exception about static class ?

```
2023-07-11 23:41:44,140 ERROR [ignite-sink-connector|task-1] WorkerSinkTask{id=ignite-sink-connector-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask) [task-thread-ignite-sink-connector-1]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext.getStreamer(IgniteSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask.put(IgniteSinkTask.java:118)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:583)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:336)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:237)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: In order to resolve the issue, you need to add or set the plugin path to the Kafka Connect properties correctly. After that, the plugin is loaded and the class is accessible. Make sure you see the "Added plugin" message in the Kafka Connect log. Double check that the plugin.path is correctly set. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544969/kafka-ignite-sink-connector) for more information and this might help you in resolving this issue.

Comment: yes plugin is added. Since plugin call this sink task. When plugin was not in path then there will be another exception